# Recomendation for Good Books To Read to a 2-Year-Old Child

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, children-parenting, books-generally

Any recommendations on books I can read with my 2 year old to help introduce her to Torah or other Judaism concepts? She can't read, but she copies everything I say and shows me things so I think there is some opportunity to share HaShem with her.

Please indicate in your answer what qualities of the book have caused you to recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

I got [My First Parsha Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006ZN2Q4E) when i was around 5, and has been passed down through the siblings, with everyone getting something out of it.

It's geared for children 3-8, but i think that a 2 year old should still be able to appreciate some of the things when you read it to her. It is in English.

It contains summaries of each parsha, picking out things that should appeal to young kids, especially the "classic" stories.

Answer (score 4):

We have "[Tell me the story of the Parsha](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0074NJ8SG)." (I got it for much cheaper in a store in Brooklyn)

First off, it is laminated!  So no kids turning pages or spilling on it will ruin it!

But in terms of content, it has a nice synopsis of the main story of the Parsha, incorporating midrashim to a degree, with colorful pictures.  It introduces my son to the stories of the Chumash in a way that he enjoys listening.  He asks questions from the pictures, and if I know the answers, I'm able to expand.

My only gripe is the illustrations - every page is a mirror image of the opposite page. But they are colorful and detailed, so they're ok.

We also have "[Boruch learns about Shabbos](http://www.judaicapress.com/Boruch-Learns-About-Shabbos.html)" and "[Boruch learns his Brochos](http://www.judaicapress.com/Boruch-Learns-His-Brochos.html)" - both of them have *terrible* rhyming schemes, but my kids enjoy them and they teach basic concepts of Shabbos and Berachos.  They are cute books.

Comment: Could you link to it somewhere?

Comment: @Scimonster Yeah, but better to go buy it in a store.

Answer (score 3):

["Uh-uh, not now," said the cow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0911643184). Hard to get now, unfortunately, but truly a unique book in that it gives you the opportunity to make animal sounds with the child while emphasizing the value of Shabbos.

Most anything else illustrated by Norman Nodel targeted at the young age market (few words per page) is going to be great.

Comment: That's a great book, +1.

Answer (score 2):

As a parent of a nice bunch of children these have been my kids favorites at the age of 2.

The Very Best Place for a Penny by Dina Rosenfeld - about Tzedaka

Get Ready for Shabbos with Mendel by Naftali Cisner - about Shabbos

Dovy and the Surprise Guests by Goldie Golding - about Hachnosas Orchim & Shabbos

Let's go to Shul by Rikki Berenfeld - about Shul

Who's that sleeping on my sofabed? by Ruby Grossblatt - about Hachnosas Orchim & people's feelings

Labels for Laibel by Dina Rosenfeld - about sharing

These were my older kids favorites and remain my younger kids favorites. All of these are well written, captivating, nice pictures, and interesting.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Labels for Laibel!  A frum book without a miserable rhyming scheme!